# Error in importing database in MySQL

Tags: mysql, import

I'm trying to import the database in MySQL but it kept on showing this error saying that 'no database selected'. Is there something wrong with my xampp? I've installed xampp v3.0.12.. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I don't know what to do. :( I need to import this badly.This is the reason why I can't log in to wordpress. dAny help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Error
SQL query:

--

### -- Database: `eucincor_psuccessdb.sql`

### -- --------------------------------------------------------

### -- Table structure for table `wp_additional_attendees`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `wp_additional_attendees` (

 `id` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `attendee_id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0',
 `x_attedee_name` VARCHAR( 45 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `x_attendee_email` VARCHAR( 45 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =1;
```

MySQL said:

## 1046 - No database selected

Answer (score 0):

you might would have forgotten to use database.
the dump file does not contain the

```
create database eucincor_psuccessdb
use eucincor_psuccessdb
```

either add manually this in the `eucincor_psuccessdb.sql` file or just type these commands before importing your database.

hope it worked!

Comment: hi! thanks for your suggestion! :) anyway, I've noticed that mysql accepts only 2,048kb size of database but mine is 3.45mb. do you know any solutions on how can I import the database?